# Window function closure

Tags: sql, sql-server

When trying to perform this query in SSMS an error is created:

```
select *,
    cume_dist() over list
from Products
window list as (order by productID)
```

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 65
> Incorrect syntax near 'list'.
> Completion time: 2024-01-24T08:37:17.2335554+02:00

How to solve?

Comment: That is not a valid `SQL Server` query. You need to refer to the documentation for the proper syntax

Comment: You can't use predefined window in sql server but have to write it out in every window function call like: `ROW_NUMBER() Over(...)`

Comment: If you want a compatible query for your version of SQL Server, add a [mcve] to clarify your needs.

Comment: @siggemannen - you can in SQL Server 2022 https://dbfiddle.uk/Kz2t2nsl - but presumably the questioner is on some previous version or lower compat level.

Comment: @MartinSmith wow, can't believe i missed that, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2022 added support for ANSI SQL feature T612, Advanced OLAP operations' `<window clause>`.

Previous versions compatible query:

```
select *,
       cume_dist() over (order by productID)
from Products
```